# Bash, looping through space delimited array for creating files causes it to hang

Tags: bash, file, for-loop, git-bash, cat

As briefed in the title of question, I am trying to create some 5-6 files when newly installed GitBash into Windows 10 64Bit and I am stuck with a hanging `for` loop which is intended to create those files.

Now currently I have couple files existing already in GitBash's Home folder as below:

```
.minttyrc
.gitconfig
```

But as I am trying to create a generalized once-n-for-all script, I decided to write code such that it ignore if file already exists.

So after seeing that using `~` inside quotes(double, so not even thought of single) converts it into literal string, so had to relent to below code:

```
gbfiles=(".profile" ".bashrc" ".minttyrc" ".gitconfig" ".bash_profile")
for file in ${gbfiles[@]}; do [ -f ~/$file ] || cat > ~/$file; done;
```

But this code after creating `.profile` goes berserk and hangs the `for` loop and doesn't create a single file after that.

Why so happens(is it due to loop stuck at any error, I used conditional for suppressing/ignoring errors) and could anyone help achieving what's intended ?

Comment: `cat > ~/$file` will wait for input data since you haven't provided any. Try `> ~"/${file}"` (no `cat`) or `true > ~"/${file}"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked like a charm !! Didn't know that waiting thing about `cat` though, assumed that `cat` is like `echo` will take blank as data if none provided...

Comment: It's like most programs that take filename arguments. If no filenames are provided, they default to reading stdin.

Comment: BTW, you should quote your variables: `"${gbfiles[@]}"` and `~/"$file"`

Comment: Agree with @Barmar - Quote your vars - so they can have spaces in them - and so you can refer to files that have a space in the name / path [they exist - people use them - alot more these days than in the past].